# Two entities are generating strange

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

CartItem entity

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name="cart_item")
    public class CartItem {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer cartItemId;

        private int quantity;

        private double price;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
        private Product product;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
        private Cart cart;
```

Cart entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cart")
public class Cart {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer cart_id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<CartItem> cartItem;

    private double totalPrice;
```

CartItemService

```
public void save(User user,CartItem cartItem,String name){
    Cart cart = cartRepository.findCartByUser(user);
    Product product = productRepository.findByName(name);
    cartItem.setProduct(product);
    cartItem.setCart(cart);
    cartItem.setQuantity(1);
    cartItem.setPrice(product.getPrice());
    cartItemRepository.save(cartItem);
}
```

I don't know what is wrong, but I assigned to every user 1 cart, and every time user puts something in cart, or when cart is created, it is adding +1 to both entities id(if there is 2 carts and user adds item to cart ItemCartId will be 3)

[image]

Comment: Side note: `double` is not the appropriate type for monetary values.  You should be using `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the strategy you're using is using the same sequence to generate ids throughout multiple tables. Replacing it with this should solve your problem:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```